# Enum type of conversion when using Spring web service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, enums

This would be an extension to the following question:

[Spring web service request and response for mapping having list of other objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186934/spring-web-service-request-and-response-for-mapping-having-list-of-other-objects/22187036#22187036)

What if the Question POJO had an enum type. How do I represent that in the ajax call when making a request and using @RequestBody.

eg:

```
public class Question {

    private String questionText;

    List<Options> options;

    private QuestionTye questionType

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }

    //getters and setters for options


}
```

Enum looks as follows:

```
public enum QuestionType {

    MCQ, FILL_IN_THE_BLANK, QUESTION_AND_ANSWER, MATCH_THE_FOLLOWING

}
```

How should I then format my JSON when sending it to the server?

Comment: Try serializing the pojo you currently have. The result will be the json format you need.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by serialize it? I can extend Serializable. But then what?

Comment: No. Spring uses Jackson to convert an objet to a json string. Try it out directly.

Comment: Yes. I used Google's JSON converter library called GSON and that worked great. I didnt even have to write to file or anything. Just a sysout helped. Thanks again for your inputs.

Comment: Note that Spring uses Jackson by default, so you should probably test with that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have the jackson API on the classpatch, add an annotated "Create" method. I also like to add a "None" option to my enums to avoid null pointer:

```
public enum QuestionType {

    MCQ, FILL_IN_THE_BLANK, QUESTION_AND_ANSWER, MATCH_THE_FOLLOWING, NONE;

    @JsonCreator
    public QuestionType create(String input){

        QuestionType result;
        if("MCQ".equals(input)){

            result = MCQ;
        }
        else if(/*snip etc*/){

        }//etc
        else{

           result = NONE;//Or null or throw an exception .. whatever
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```